# how to import function from models.py to run a cron job?

Tags: python, django, cron

I'm trying to run a cron job using celery. Problem is I need to run a function in models.py,  this sounds weird but let me demonstrate it in code.

```
class Post(models.Model):
rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)


def get_score(self):
    upvote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=True).count()
    devote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=False).count()
    return hot(upvote_count, devote_count, self.pub_date.replace(tzinfo=None)

)
```

Here I need to run a get_score in the background every second. so for celery.py I'm inporting this function.

```
from  main.models import get_score

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')),
    name="task_get_score",
    ignore_result=True
)

def task_get_score():
    get_score()
    logger.info("running cron job")
```

then it says from  main.models import get_score
ImportError: cannot import name get_score

Or do I need to run a formula function in rank.py inside my utils folder

```
def hot(ups, downs, date):

    s = score(ups, downs)
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(sign * order + seconds / 45000, 7)
```

Is this the one I should run cron job on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First setup your djnago project in your script then use get_score method

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.append('/var/www/projects/project_name/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
from django.conf import settings

from  main.models import get_score

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/15')),
    name="task_get_score",
    ignore_result=True
)

def task_get_score():
    get_score()
    logger.info("running cron job")
```

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain this little bit in detail? make script of what? where does the code up there belong? I should use get_score method for the cron job right? Sorry I'm still very noob...

Comment: Thank you, but I think I set everything right  but get ImportError: cannot import name get_score